# observeForever inside a singleton object

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-livedata, finalizer

I'm writing my first app in Kotlin and am using Firebase for auth,db & storage. I have singleton object to wrap each Firebase service to reduce coupling. In my Authentication object, I hold the current user in a LiveData to allow ViewModels to reference it and Fragments to observe it, and it works great. I would like to observe it also from the Database object, to allow it to keep the current user's Firestore document loaded. My Firebase objects are not Lifecycle aware so `observeForever` is my option. The function's comment states that: "You should manually call {@link #removeObserver(Observer)} to stop observing this LiveData.", but I didn't find any "finalize"/"onCleanUp"/... handlers in Kotlin objects. Should I worry about it (in my case I kind of want to really observe forever)?

code:

```
object Authentication {
    private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().apply {
        addAuthStateListener { _currentUser.value = currentUser }
    }

    private val _currentUser: MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?> =
        MutableLiveData<FirebaseUser?>().apply { value = auth.currentUser }
    val currentUser: LiveData<FirebaseUser?> = _currentUser

...
}

object Database {
    init {
        Authentication.currentUser.observeForever { switchUserDocument(it) }
    }

...
}
```

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do not need to remove observer from your `Singletone` you should ignore android lint in your case.